# Decode Base64 and zipped file in Python

Tags: python, base64, zip, decode, gmail-api

From a Gmail API I get attachments encoded in Base64.
"cfiles" is a list of Base64 while I made sure that all Base64 is clean and no metadata of the files are included.

I use the following code to decode and unzip the files.

```
for x in cfiles:
    try:
        ffiles = base64.urlsafe_b64decode(x + '=' * (4 - len(x) % 4))        
        ffiles = zlib.decompress(ffiles)
    except Exception as e: 
        logging.getLogger().error(str(e))
```

The logger gives following error.

```
Error -3 while decompressing data: incorrect header check
```

Any idea what I need to change?
First part (decoding base64) does work well.

Comment: Are you sure that the thing you've Base64-decoded is a zipfile? It seems it's not. Try inspecting the first 8-16 bytes of `ffiles`, what do you see?

Comment: ffile: b'PK\x03\x04\x14\x00\x00\x08\x08\x00\xed;_Ur\x8ee3\\\n\x00\x00\x9f\x9f\x00\x00$\x00\x00\x00dashboard-ops_associate/ac_slots.csv.....

cfile= UEsDBBQAAAgIAO07X1VyjmUzXAoAAJ-fAAAkAAAAZGFzaGJvYXJkLW9wc19hc3NvY2lhdGUvYWNfc2xvdHMuY3N2pZ3LbiPHDob3eQotcwAP0lV9kZRdrg

Comment: That looks like the start of a zip file without base 64 encoding.

Comment: @pmqs Well of course. `ffiles` is the base64-decoded cfile. So it _does_ look like a Zip header. Why it doesn't decode, I have no further idea.